# Adding Eclipse menu contribution to a group

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to tell a menuContribution's command to place itself inside a menu. (The menu is defined in one of the plug-in's dependencies)

I'm able to place an action with the deprecated API org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus by setting:

```
menubarPath: com.example.navigator.menu
```

However not with the new API element org.eclipse.ui.menus. I'm trying to set a menuCommand's:

```
locationURI: popup:com.example.navigator.menu
```

I created a plug-in to demonstrate what's happening:

[image]

Could it be that the 2 APIs cannot work together?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the APIs;

action's menubarPath and a menuContribution's locationURI didn't seem to understand each other's "addressing". Or at least I couldn't figure it out.

It's weird that the Extension Wizard generates an extension that's using the deprecated API.